# Django Admin - Configuring Change List Entries

Tags: django, django-admin, django-pagination

In Django admin, As of now, change list of a model shows 100 entries per page. Is there any configuration available to customize this limit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a list_per_page attribute in your Django admin.py:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_per_page